# Axis2/CXF SAOP web service receiving huge inline attachments

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf, apache-axis

I use Java SOAP web-service based on Axis2 1.4.1 to exchange data and attachments since years; no matter so far even if big attachments since the web-service implements MTOM.
This till last week, when a webservice WS client started sending huge attachments (around 1GB) as base64 inline text within the SOAP body (no MTOM no SwA).
I was confident that Axis2 attachment caching feature would solve also in this case, but this is not true and OutOfMemory occurs. 
After some attempts my understanding is that attachments are cached to disk (and not kept in memory) only if the WS client sends them as MIME parts.If sent as base64 text within the SOAP body they are kept in memory.

I also tried to replace Axis2 with CXF (I'm prepared to change my WS framework if it is the only solution) but I experimented exactly the same behavior.

I'm wondering if I'm missing something or someone having my same issue found a solution.
I cant't believe that my webservice can manage big attachments only if the client implements MTOM.

Thanks in advance for any possible suggestion.